# Search words by similarity in MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql

So I have this MySQL query:

```
$search = $_POST['search'];
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM `data` WHERE name='$search';
$rs = mysqli_query($dbconfig, $SQL);
```

I use this code to search data into the database, with the word that has been submitted by the form. The problem is, the query only shows up results if the search word matches the data in the database.

For example, if I have a file named `advertisement.png` and I search for this file, it will only show up if I search for the exact same word.

If I search for `advertisement.png` it will show `advertisement.png`, but if I search for `advertisement` it will not show up. What I want, is to search data that are similar to the key word provided in the form.

So if I search`"advert"` it shows up results that are similar to this word.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the answers below don't solve your need, you might want to look into full text search.

Comment: And don't forget, ALWAYS use `mysqli_real_escape_string` with any input in SQL. No answer mention that...

Comment: Yes, I use mysqli_real_escape_string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use LIKE operator with % for both end as follows

```
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM `data` WHERE name LIKE '%$search%';
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `LIKE` operator with % at end

```
$search = $_POST['search'];
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM `data` WHERE name LIKE '$search%';
$rs = mysqli_query($dbconfig, $SQL);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Like` Operator.
The Code will be

```
$search = $_POST['search'];
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM `data` WHERE name LIKE '%$search%';
$rs = mysqli_query($dbconfig, $SQL);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have use % on start and end of your secrch value.

```
SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE Country LIKE '%land%';
```

Answer (score 0):

Ther is also some SQL functions for comparing string you could use like STRCMP(str1, str2), returns 0 if both strings are equal

Answer (score 0):

$sql = "select * from table_name name like '%search_key%' ";

Here % means all keyword you type from left and right. Any keyword matches it will give you the result